# MySQL query performance improvment?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I've got a query that runs painfully slow and need some advice on how to improve its performance.

First table: results has approximately 10k rows.

```
'CREATE TABLE `results` (
`ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`matchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`matchShooterID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
`ResultDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
... more columns ...
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9767 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Indexes

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment   
'results', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'ID', 'A', '3462', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Second table: wp_usermeta has approximately 10k rows.

```
'CREATE TABLE `wp_usermeta` (
  `umeta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`umeta_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11170 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'; 

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
wp_usermeta 0   PRIMARY 1   umeta_id    A   6241                BTREE       
wp_usermeta 1   user_id 1   user_id A   780             BTREE       
wp_usermeta 1   meta_key    1   meta_key    A   104 191     YES BTREE
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        pr.ShooterID AS ShooterID,
        pr.RangeID AS RangeID,
        (SELECT um.meta_value
            FROM
                wp_usermeta um
            WHERE
                ((um.meta_key = 'first_name')
                    AND (um.user_id = pr.ShooterID))),
        (SELECT 
                COUNT(0)
            FROM
                wp_plinker_results
            WHERE
                ((results.ShooterID = pr.ShooterID)
                    AND (results.RangeID = pr.RangeID))) AS GameCount
FROM
    (results pr
    JOIN wp_usermeta um ON ((pr.ShooterID = um.user_id)));
```

What I'm trying to get is a count of the games (a result record) for each shooterID by date. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Updated: EXPLAIN output and indexes added

```
1   PRIMARY pr  ALL                 3462    100.00  Using temporary
1   PRIMARY um  ref user_id user_id 8   shootpli_plpress.pr.ShooterID   8   100.00  Using where; Using index; Distinct
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  wp_plinker_results  ALL                 3462    100.00  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  um  ref user_id,meta_key    user_id 8   shootpli_plpress.pr.ShooterID   8   100.00  Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: Show us what your indexes are, please. Also the `explain` result. And an explanation of what the query is accomplishing would help to rewrite it.

Comment: Note that your second subquery has `results.ShooterID = pr.ShooterID` but `pr` is aliased to `results`.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, `results` has no foreign key indexes? That's gonna cause performance problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a join to wp_usermeta, you need to join with linker_results to improve performance

```
    SELECT pr.ShooterID AS ShooterID,
            pr.RangeID AS RangeID,
            CASE um.meta_key WHEN um.meta_key ='first_name' THEN um.meta_value ELSE 'NO_META_VALUE' END as meta_value,
            COUNT(0) AS GameCount
    FROM
        results pr
        JOIN wp_usermeta um ON ((pr.ShooterID = um.user_id))
        JOIN wp_plinker_results um ON ((results.ShooterID = pr.ShooterID)
                    AND (results.RangeID = pr.RangeID))
    GROUP BY pr.ShooterID,pr.RangeID,um.meta_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to MySQL 5.7.8 or newer, the `wp_usermeta` table would be better done as a JSON column on the user table.

Also note that you've mixed up `results` and `pr` in your query, they're aliases to the same table. `pr` should probably be an alias to `wp_plinker_results`.

---

Since you're already joining with wp_usermeta, the first subquery can be replaced with a simple where clause.

```
WHERE um.meta_key = 'first_name'
```

Then you can select `um.meta_value AS FirstName`.

I believe the second subquery can also be done with a join and a group by

```
JOIN wp_plinker_results pr ON results.ShooterID = pr.ShooterID AND
                              results.RangeID = pr.RangeID
GROUP BY pr.ShooterID, pr.RangeID
```

Put it all together...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        results.ShooterID AS ShooterID,
        results.RangeID AS RangeID,
        um.meta_value AS FirstName,
        COUNT(pr.id) AS GameCount
FROM results
JOIN wp_usermeta um ON um.user_id = results.ShooterID
JOIN wp_plinker_results pr ON results.ShooterID = pr.ShooterID AND
                              results.RangeID = pr.RangeID
WHERE um.meta_key = 'first_name'
GROUP BY pr.ShooterID, pr.RangeID
```

This will be much easier for MySQL to optimize.

It's very important that all your foreign keys are declared as such so they're indexed. It's also probably important that `um.meta_key` be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

WP, wake up!  Your indexes are a problem!

```
PRIMARY KEY (`umeta_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
```

-->

Get rid of `umeta_id` -- both the column and index -- it is useless and slows things down.

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, meta_key), -- to speed up the main query
INDEX(meta_key)  -- if needed for other queries
```

Beware of mixing `COUNT`, `JOIN`, and `GROUP BY`.  `JOIN` inflates the number of rows, then the `COUNT` happens and give you an inflated value -- before the `GROUP BY` deflates again.  Do not mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`; the latter effectively does the former.

(It would be helpful to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_plinker_results`, too.)

I don't see the purpose of `wp_plinker_results`, so I removed it.

```
SELECT  r.ShooterID,
        r.RangeID,
        DATE(r.ResultDate) AS date,
        ( SELECT meta_value
             FROM wp_usermeta
             WHERE user_id = r.ShooterID
               AND meta_key = 'first_name'
        ) AS FirstName,
        COUNT(*) AS GameCount
FROM results AS r
GROUP BY r.ShooterID, r.RangeID, DATE(r.ResultDate)
```

It *may* be useful to have this index for `results`:

```
INDEX(ShooterID, RangeID, ResultDate)
```

Is `results.ShooterID` supposed to be `results.matchShooterId`?  (And there are other things that are unclear in the question!)

Comment: thanks for the input. I'm currently chasing my tail with my hosting provider because I don't have permission to add FK's! Hopefully, that will be resolved soon.

Comment: FKs are not a requirement of databases.  You have some particular need?

Comment: It turns out that the primary key in my parent table is set to auto-increment. Because of this, MySql won't let me add PK's. This forced me to look for a solution that did not require PK's to improve performance. Based on this, Mit's answer pointed me in the right direction and now my query performance is acceptable. Thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: Foreign Keys  slow down actions, when not Cascading.  A `PRIMARY KEY` is an index, so `JOINs` are efficient, even without an FK defined.

Comment: At least get rid of `(191)`.